# retrieve and display php array values when retrieving all records from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I am displaying the complete record of the user in the My profile section, I am fetching all the rows , but the problem is within the rows I've got two fields as arrays, which are 'secondarySubject' and 'secondaryGrade' now I want the display to be something like this

> 2002-2004 ----------- A Level ------- School Name

```
                  Science          A
                  Maths            B
```

I am able to display them but it prints the dates, school name and level name with every subject rather than just once for all the subjects. I am posting my code, can someone pleaseeee help me with it.

```
$result2 = $db->query('

SELECT *

FROM secondaryEducation

WHERE userID = "'.$graduateID.'"

ORDER BY secondaryFinishDate DESC

');



$totalRows2 = mysql_num_rows($result2);

if($totalRows2 > 0)

{

    $html .= '<h2>Secondary Education: '.$option.'</h2>';


    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))

    {



        $startYear = formatDate($row['secondaryStartDate'], 'Y');

        $finishYear = formatDate($row['secondaryFinishDate'], 'Y');

        if (!empty($row['secondaryGrade']))

            $secondaryGrade = getSecondaryGradeName($row['secondaryGrade']);

        else

            $secondaryGrade = $row['secondaryGradeCustom'];

        $html .= '



            <div class="secondaryListing">

                <div><strong>'.$startYear.' - '.$finishYear.' '.stripslashes($row['secondarySchool']).'</strong></div>

                <div>'.stripslashes(getSecondaryLevelName($row['secondaryLevel'])).' in '.stripslashes(getSecondarySubjectName($row['secondarySubject'])).' - '.stripSlashes($secondaryGrade).'</div>

            </div><!-- End education listing -->



        ';



    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like those are inside the while statement. Every time it loops it will include it. Try moving it outside the while statement.

Comment: Hi, the loop is to fetch all the records, I want the school name to be displayed just once for records of that school.